# linux get all threads started by this process

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

In Linux, with C++, is there a way to programmatically get a list of all the `pthread_t`s that have been started for this process? I know you can look at:

```
/proc/$(getpid())/task/
```

But is there a library call that already does that?

Comment: Maybe ThreadSanitizer? https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual?

Answer (score 0):

No, and for good reasons. Say a library created a thread. What could you do usefully with the `pthread_t` for that thread. Also, you couldn't use the `pthread_t` for anything even if you got it, because the thread could terminate (or be joined) immediately after it was returned to you, which would make using it undefined behavior.

If you could do something useful for a `pthread_t` because you know what's it's doing or how it's coded and when it's valid, you could also track the `pthread_t`.

Comment: You might be writing a layer to report thread information/activity within your process. Windows has a `Thread32First`/`Thread32Next` set of functions for walking all the threads in a process.

Comment: @Sean But you couldn't do that anyway. There's nothing you could do with a list of `pthread_t`s other than count them, since it's illegal to access them (because they may no longer be valid because a thread can terminate or be joined at any time).